# Xcode maximum number of registered iPhone devices

Tags: xcode

long time ago I worked with Xcode.
now I would like to work again with it and I have a new iPhone.

Xcode shows the following error:
This request is forbidden for security reasons: Your development team has reached the maximum number of registered iPhone devices.

My Apple Developer Program membership has expired.
Is there an free "program" available only for testing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit the [Apple Developer Account](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev7a05c5ce1) and then when you want to publish some app to the App Store you can enrol the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/).

Comment: I have an apple developer account. I would like to test my app on my iPhone, not on the simulator. this is only possible with the an apple developer program?

Comment: It should be possible. Here's a [tutorial](https://steemit.com/xcode/@ktsteemit/xcode-free-provisioning) I used in the past. And here you can find the [official documentation](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev40df0d9fa).

Comment: Yes, but this is the problem. There I get the error: `This request is forbidden for security reasons.Your development team has reached the maximum number of registered iPhone devices.` After the step "c" in your tutorial

Comment: Can you see your devices list from the developer account page? Specifically in the `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` section.

Comment: Ok, I see that from the free account page there is no way to access the list of associated devices. Probably in the past you enrolled the paid program and added more than 3 devices (did you?), then it expired and you are now stuck with those with no possibility to remove them. I am afraid you have to [contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/topic/select) and ask if they can do it for you.

Comment: yes, that can be possible. I contacted apple. thanks !

Comment: Sure, let me know✌️